# :first selector doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to use `:first`:

```
$(function(){

    $('.awardDltBtn:first').remove();

});
```

to select the first matched element but it doesn't work in my case.

HTML:

```
<section>
</section>
```

I also tried `first-of-type` and `nth-of-type`.

Comment: removes the first button if you add jquery library http://jsfiddle.net/6qh50ce3/

Comment: your trying to remove the first section or the first div?

Comment: You forget to load jQuery. And take care with repeated IDs, an ID should be unique!!

Comment: You have not included jquery in jsfiddle, i have updated it

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to include jquery for using jquery code. Then your code is fine for removing the delete button. if you want to remove the complete row associated with that then use:

```
$('.awardDltBtn:first').prevAll().addBack().remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Luakxf5/)**